# Filter RelationQuery by relation_type

Tags: entities

I have some 2-point-relations called 'is_member_of' where the source endpoint is a person and the target endpoint is a group.

I like to list all of the members (without using a view).

In the code I build a relation query with the nid 1234 as target (last option = 1)

```
$query = relation_query('node',1234,1);
$results = $query->execute();
dpm($results);
```

This lists ALL relations to the nid 1234. I only want to have relations of the

```
relation_type='is_member_of'
```

Is there a fieldCondition which can do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using relation module ?

Comment: Of course I do :-) I already get ALL results with the endpoint 1234 as target. But I only want to get the relations named "is_member_of".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `RelationQuery` is just an `EntityFieldQuery` under the hood, and since `relation_type` is the bundle key of the `relation` entity type, both

```
$query = relation_query('node',1234,1);
$results = $query->entityCondition('bundle', 'is_member_of')->execute();
```

and

```
$query = relation_query('node',1234,1);
$results = $query->propertyCondition('relation_type', 'is_member_of')->execute();
```

should work.

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked. I thought of something like a fieldCondition but this failed. Now it works.